# QueryAllAccounts returns either Parent or Child but not both when querying from Child

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, fuel-sdk

Using the SFMC Soap API with QueryAllAccounts on seems to be behaving interestingly at the moment and I'm not sure if just me going crazy or it was always like this.

1. When in the child BU and setting QueryAllAccounts to true, only the
   parent objects are returned.
2. When in the child BU and setting to
   false, only the child objects are returned.
3. When in the parent BU
   and setting QueryAllAccounts to true, all objects are returned in
   instance (parent and child).
4. When in the parent BU and setting to
   false, only the parent objects are returned.

Based on my understanding and also documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieverequest.htm) scenario 1 should return at least the current BU, and possibly Parent but it is not happening

I tried setting ClientIDs and nothing changed (documentation confirms that should be the case)

example for scenario 1 is here for Query but I also tested with folders and same results

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>QueryDefinition</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```